# rails 3 table complicated sorting

Tags: sorting, ruby-on-rails-3.2, html-table

I am making a sorting function in order to sort a list of users. This sorting function designed to sort according to attributes (columns). User model has a column company_id but I don't want to sort by number, I want to sort by name of the company. BTW,

> company :has_many users

and

> user :belongs_to company

This is my index.html.erb:

```
<table class="pretty" border="1" cellpadding="10">  
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th><%= sortable "name" %></th>
    <th><%= sortable "email" %></th>
    <th><%= sortable "company_id" %></th>
    <th>DELETE</th>
  </tr>  

  <% for user in @users %>  
  <tr class="<%= cycle('oddrow', 'evenrow') -%>">
    <td><%= gravatar_for user %></td>
    <td><%= link_to user.name, user %></td>
    <td><%= user.email %></td>
    <td><%= user.company.name unless user.company_id.blank? %></td>
    <td><% if current_user.admin? || ( ( current_user.developer? && !current_user?(user) ) && (user.boss_id == current_user.id) ) %>
      || <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                              data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
        <% end %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
<%= will_paginate @users %>
```

This is sortable function from application_helper.rb:

```
def sortable(column, title = nil)  
    title ||= column.titleize
    css_class = (column == sort_column) ? "current #{sort_direction}" : nil
    direction = (column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc") ? "desc" : "asc"  
    link_to title, params.merge(:sort => column, :direction => direction, :page => nil), {:class => css_class}
end
```

And this is users_controller.rb:

```
helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction
def index
    @users = User.where(:developer => false, :admin => false).search(params[:search]).order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction).paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page])
end

private
def sort_column
  User.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "name"
end

def sort_direction
  %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "asc"
end
```

So, how can I modify this in order to sort by Company.name rather than User.company_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by changing `<%= sortable "company_id" %>` to `<%= sortable("name", "Company") %>` and changing

> User.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "name"

to

> (( User.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ) || ( Company.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) )) ? params[:sort] : "name"